# cpu cgroup controller parameters rt_runtime_us and rt_period_us does not exist in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, cgroup

We are migrating Ubuntu from 18.04 to 22.04 in our product, while this activity we are not able to load our cgconfig.conf file which was loading fine in 18.04.

```
# cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf
cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup, requested group parameter does not exist
```

We had to comment out below two entries in cgconfig.conf file to make the cgconfig.conf file load in Ubuntu 22.04

```
     cpu {
                 cpu.shares = 1024;
                 # Reallocate CPU resources once per second
-                cpu.rt_period_us="1000000";
+                #cpu.rt_period_us="1000000";
                 # Allocate 50% of runtime to tasks in the cgroup
-                cpu.rt_runtime_us="500000";
+                #cpu.rt_runtime_us="500000";
         }
         memory {
                 memory.limit_in_bytes = 373737M
```

The changes required to use cgroup V1 are already made by setting "unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"

Can't we use rt_runtime_us and rt_period_us in Ubuntu 22.04? What are the equivalent alternate parameters in Ubuntu 22.04.